# Upload a file and hit a backend API with the file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, fetch, multipartform-data

There is backend API for which an acceptable **curl command** is:

```
curl -i -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
  -F "file=*path-to-file-on-your-local*" \
'http://localhost:9000/data/upload'
```

where *path-to-file-on-your-local* can be something like: **/Users/me/Downloads/abc.csv**

On the frontend side, I have the following:

```
<TextField
      name="filePath"
      placeholder="Enter filePath .."
      type="text"
      errorText="This field is required"
      onChange={this._handleFilePathInput}
 /><br />
```

Finally in the server.js, I do:

```
fetch('http://localhost:9000/data/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type:multipart/form-data'},
                body: file
            }).then...........
```

This is not working. The file is not going to the backend. How will I write the **fetch** API to accomplish the same?

Comment: I believe the headers option is expecting either a Headers() object or an object literal. For instance: `headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}`.

Comment: @TPorter: Yaa sorry. Still I'm not able to make the http call

Comment: Do the headers in the network request look correct in your browser dev tools?